# Parsing complex datatype between UWP and unity script

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

I have been trying to find a solution of sending complex datatypes between a UWP app and unity scripts. Specifically I have in my start-up app.xaml.cs, an initialization of different data that is saved on the device and communication to Azure App Service, but I can't seem to make the information available in unity. How can I access this data in a unity script?

I have searched around and the closest I have come is [`ApplicationUri`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) but unsure how to share the info from UWP. Since it does not seem to be the same folder as when I am in UWP and access `Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer`.

Can anyone explain how I share data from the UWP specific code to the Unity scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any of your C# scripts in Unity, do this:

```
public class MyBridge
{
    public static object MyThingToStore;
}
```

Now, in App.xaml.cs, do this:

```
MyBridge.MyThingToStore = ....;
```

While my example shows how to do it for basic object types, it should work for most stuff. You can call any public methods too, but beware that by default you're on another thread in App.xaml.cs file. If you want to execute code on the Unity thread in App.xaml.cs, do this:

```
appCallbacks.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
{
    // Code to execute on Unity's main thread.
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but requires static variables. It is not possible like using appressources or seralize the object and deserialize in the script?
Is it possible to get a reference to the script as to not use static variables

Comment: What's wrong with statics, exactly? You could use GameObject.Find to find your game object, but that to me seems like unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Statics are in the global scope and when multiple people have access to the code they can change it, and therefore I have no guarantees about the state of the object. `GameObject.Find` I thought this was only available inside the unity scripts and not from the UWP code, since `GameObject` is never instantiated. But it is possible to use it ? (I will taste when I am to do that project again).

Comment: GameObject.Find is a static method.

Comment: Could you share resource for achieving communication between unity standalone build and Windows universal application.